# Is there a generalization of the concept of variance for a collection of probability distributions?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, definition

If I have a collection of numbers, I can obtain a measure of how much they're "spread" by computing the sample variance of them, i.e. $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2~,$$ where $\mu$ is the sample mean.

I was looking for a similar measure of "spreadness" but of a collection of probability distributions. For example, the following collection of probability distributions:
[image: high variance]

would have high variance, whereas the collection:

[image: low variance]

would have lower variance.

Is there such a generalization of this concept for a collection of probability distributions?

---

#### My thoughts so far:

It seems intuitive to me to try drawing a parallel between this and the definition of variance for real numbers, as described above.

One thing I could come up with was to define it as the sum of the squared "distances" to the "mean distribution". In the context of distributions, I would interpret the mean distribution as simply the mean of the pdfs (that is $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nF_i(x)$, where each $F_i$ is one of the distributions in the collection), and perhaps the "distance" as the [Wasserstein metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric).

That is, the variance of a collection of distributions $F_i(x)$ would be computed as

$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\text{W}(F_i,\bar{F})^2~,$$

where $\text{W}(a,b)$ is the Wasserstein distance between distributions $a$ and $b$, and $\bar{F}$ is computed as $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nF_i(x)~.$$

This doesn't seem so crazy, but it's based purely in my intuition. It would be nice to know if someone else already has a more developed notion on how to generalize variance in this direction.

Comment: You need to check for a generalizations of the Kullback-Leibler divergence, e.g., https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00537520.

Comment: @BruceET Why not use the Wasserstein distance, as I mentioned?

Comment: @V.Vancak Could you explain a bit more why do you think this is what I should be researching? I'm an amateur in this field. Reading the abstract in the provided link didn't really help me understand how this relates to my question.

Comment: You are looking for a metric that measures distance between distributions. Such a pseudo-metric is Kullback-Leibler, however, this metric measures "distance" between two distributions, while you need to examine more than two. Thus you need to generalize this notion. There is no unique generalization, but you can use the linked paper to check what else is available.

Comment: @V.Vancak Thanks, now it's very clear. One question comes to mind, though: if I need a metric, why are you referring to KL divergence? Why not the Wasserstein metric?

Comment: Well, as a statistician the KL is the default go to pseudo-metric (as it connected to the AIC criteria, the MLE and so on). IMHO, Wasserstein's metric is no popular outside of the CS community. So unfortunately I cannot say nothing about its properties...

Comment: @V.Vancak I see. Thanks for your time :).